# How a convert a vector of float to uint8_t, unit32_t or other datatype?

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to write a template based function, which takes float vector as input and return vector type based on template. Below code is working fine with "int", "double", "float" etc but when I try things with datatype like "uint8_t", i got vector of required size. But when try to print values, I got empy line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> convertDattype(std::vector<float> float_vec)
{
    std::vector<T> vec;
    vec.reserve( float_vec.size() );    //  avoids unnecessary reallocations
    std::transform( float_vec.begin(), float_vec.end(),
        std::back_inserter( vec ),
        [](const float &arg) { return static_cast<T>(arg); } );
    return vec;
}


int main()
{
    const uint64_t VEC_COUNT = 10;
    std::vector<float> float_vec;
    float_vec.reserve(VEC_COUNT);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < VEC_COUNT; ++i) {
        float val = static_cast<float>((rand() % 100) / 3.0f);
        float_vec.push_back(val);
    }
    std::vector<uint8_t> data = convertDatatype<uint8_t>(float_vec);
    for(auto a : data) {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I don't know whether `std::transform` will work or not. 
I just want to convert datatype of given vector to `T`. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I know that.... But is there any way to do this conversion?

Comment: If you are sure that your float numbers are always in the range of uint8_t, your method works correctly. But printing them with `std::cout` shows the corresponding character. You can cast `a` to something else (e.g. int) before showing.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to convert a vector's data type.

```
intVector = std::vector<uint8_t>(data.begin(), data.end());
```